# window.postMessage not working without setTimeOut in React

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, postmessage

I have iFrame which loads CDN template after it receives data through JS PostMessage API

```
<iframe  ref={elemRef} style={{position: 'relative', height: '90vh', width: '100%'}} id={'myIframe'} src='https://d3hs63jqljnhg.cloudfront.net/sample3.html' frameBorder="0"></iframe>


  const elemRef = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        node.contentWindow.postMessage({call:'sendValue', value: {task: {input: taskInput}}});
      }, 500);
    }
```

If I remove `setTimeOut`, it doesn't post any message. I wonder why on the react, the window.postMessage() doesn't work unless it's used with setTimeout. There's no error at all in the console, but it has to be delayed for about 500 in order to work.

I also tried using `postMessage` API in useEffects but still I can see the frame when it console Log but I don't see `postMessage` being triggered

```
  const isIFrame = (input: HTMLElement | null): input is HTMLIFrameElement =>
    input !== null && input.tagName === 'IFRAME';

  useEffect(() => {
    const iFrame = document.getElementById('myFrame')
    console.log("iframeeeee",iFrame)
    if(isIFrame(iFrame) && iFrame && iFrame.contentWindow){
      iFrame.contentWindow.postMessage({call:'sendValue', value: {task: {input: taskInput}}}, 'https://d3hs63jqljnhg.cloudfront.net/sample3.html');
    }
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const iFrame = document.getElementById('myFrame')
    console.log("iframeeeee",iFrame)
    if(isIFrame(iFrame) && iFrame && iFrame.contentWindow){
      iFrame.contentWindow.postMessage({call:'sendValue', value: {task: {input: taskInput}}}, 'https://d3hs63jqljnhg.cloudfront.net/sample3.html');
    }
  }, [])
```

Can anyone explain that? I prefer avoiding setTimeout because it feels unreliable.

Comment: In React? Where is the react code?

Comment: Your iframe probably hasn't loaded yet, so the `.contentWindow` you get is the one of the initial `about:blank` document. I'm not into React at all, but you need to wait for the iframe's `onload` event, or if easier, `window`'s one would also do if your iframe is inlined in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @kaiido, iFrame's onload function did trick. My part part of the React code looks like below:

```
<iframe  ref={elemRef} src='https://d34gxw3jqljnhg.cloudfront.net/sample3.html' frameBorder="0"></iframe>
 
const elemRef = useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
        node.onload = () => node?.contentWindow?.postMessage({call:'sendValue', value: {task: {input: taskInput}}}, 'https://d3hs63jqljnhg.cloudfront.net/sample3.html');
    }
}, [])
```